# Remove both duplicate records using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove both the duplicate records in an XML

I already can remove the second occurrence but I need to remove both records in this case.

This is the XSLT mapping that I have

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:transform version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/ZTABLE/Record">
  <ZTABLE>
  <Record>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item[not(ID=preceding-sibling::item/ID)]" />
  </Record>
  </ZTABLE>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:transform>
```

The input XML is:

```
  <ZTABLE>
  <Record>
  <item>
  <ID>400400</ID>
  </item>
  <item>
  <ID>100100</ID>
  </item>
  <item>
  <ID>200200</ID>
  </item>
  <item>
  <ID>300300</ID>
  </item>
  <item>
  <ID>400400</ID>
  </item>
  </Record>
  </ZTABLE>
```

The expected output is

```
 <ZTABLE>
 <Record>
 <item>
 <ID>100100</ID>
 </item>
 <item>
 <ID>200200</ID>
 </item>
 <item>
 <ID>300300</ID>
 </Record>
 </ZTABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="ID" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[count(key('item', ID)) > 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

For explanation, read about [Muenchian grouping.](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)